# meaning of "speaking voice"

Tags: idioms

Occasionally, I hear someone speak favorably of a person's "speaking voice". I have no sources, but have heard the expression several times in daily activity. Is it more likely to refer  to auditory qualities or conversational style?

Comment: More the tone and musicality of the voice.

Comment: ... and the clarity of speech: everything clearly enunciated.

Comment: You will find answers to this question and others in the dictionary.  It's the best place to start.  https://www.merriam-webster.com

Comment: You'll hear this when people are talking about narrators or singers. For example, if you want someone to read an audiobook, they'll need a good "speaking voice". For singers, their "singing voice" will be different than their "speaking voice".

Answer (score 1):

According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/speaking%20voice#:%7E:text=%3A%20the%20sound%20of%20a%20person%27s,a%20very%20deep%20speaking%20voice.) a speaking voice means

> the sound of a person's voice when speaking

An example of a good speaking voice would be the voice of a narrator

Answer (score 0):

Although it might sound strange to talk about a speaking voice, bear in mind that people also have a singing voice. The two don't necessarily correspond.